# Calculating with time-periods

Tags: python, datetime

i need your help.

For example- the workingtime:

```
start = datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 19, 7, 15)
end   = datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 19, 11, 15)
```

Now we have a workingtime of 4 hours.

I need a function, module or some help where i can get "the rest of the day".

For example - the freetime:

```
freetime_begin_1 = datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 19, 0, 0)
freetime_end_1 = datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 19, 7, 15)
freetime_begin_2 = datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 19, 11, 15)
freetime_end_2 = datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 19, 23, 59)
```

I hope u understand what i mean.

Thanks.

Comment: like rest of day, can u brief more

Comment: I do not understand. First 7h15 -> 11h15 gives 4 hours not 3. Next common usage is lower included and upper excluded. With that rule free time should be 0h0 -> 7h15 + 11h15 -> 0h0 next day and hopefuly full day will last 7h15 + 4h + 12h45 = 24 heures which is more common than 22h58 !

Comment: Youŕe right with the 4 hours. Okay - i think my example was very bad - so youre are right.

Comment: @JER and why to you still skip one minute between two sequences ? *Why don't you want days to last 24 hours* ?

Comment: I want 24 hours in last. My example was bad. Sorry for that and tank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this eg:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding:utf-8
import datetime


def dt_desc(dt):
    dt = str(dt)
    days = dt[:-8]
    dt = str(dt)[-8:]
    h,m,s = map(lambda s:int(s.strip()),dt.split(":"))

    ret = "%s"%days if len(days)!=0 else ""
    ret += "%s hours "%h if h != 0 else ""
    ret += "%s minutes "%m if m != 0 else ""
    ret += "%s seconds"%s if s != 0 else ""
    return ret

start = datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 19, 7, 15)
end   = datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 19, 11, 15)
print dt_desc(end-start)

freetime_begin_1 = datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 19, 0, 0)
freetime_end_1 = datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 19, 7, 14)
freetime_begin_2 = datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 19, 11, 16)
freetime_end_2 = datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 19, 23, 59)

print dt_desc(freetime_end_1 - freetime_begin_1)
print dt_desc(freetime_end_2 - freetime_begin_2)

freetime_begin_3 = datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 19, 11, 16)
freetime_end_3 = datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 19, 23, 59)

print dt_desc(freetime_end_3 - freetime_begin_3)
```